# No reaction on click event listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a navbar item, which should call the reverseService on click, but never does.

IDE says that reverseService function is never used.

VueJS dev tool warns no problem.  When I manually change the value of the variable content is updated fine.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#" @click="reverseService">Services</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<div :class="{{ isService? '':'section' }}" id="content">
   <div class="row" v-if="!isService">
    some content
   </div>
   <div v-else>
    other content 
   </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
        isService: true,
    },
    methods: {
        reverseService: function () {
            this.isService = !this.isService;
            console.log(this.isService)
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: try an alert on `mounted()` and see what happend !

Comment: What happens if you do `<a class="nav-link" href="#" @click="isService = !isService">Services</a>`?

Comment: @ggdx nothing happens, but css effects of clicking on it work well

Comment: No, it wouldn't @Psidom spotted your error. See his answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Vue instance only controls the div (`id=content`), you need to wrap the `ul` into an element that Vue controls too:

```
<div id="app">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#" @click="reverseService">Services</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<div :class="{{ isService? '':'section' }}">
   <div class="row" v-if="!isService">
    some content
   </div>
   <div v-else>
    other content 
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In your script:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
```